# ArgumentNullException when loading content in Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I can't load textures I don't know why since my code is pretty straightforward.

```
namespace Rogue_Like_LOL
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        ScreenManager screenManager;

        public Game1()
            :base()
        {

            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            Art.Load(Content);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Art.cs :

```
    namespace Rogue_Like_LOL
    {
        static class Art
        {
            public static Texture2D Player { get; private set; }
            public static Texture2D PlayGame { get; private set; }
            public static Texture2D Exit { get; private set; }

            public static SpriteFont GameFont { get; private set; }

            public static void Load(ContentManager content)
            {
                // Player etc
                PlayGame = content.Load<Texture2D>("playgame");
                Exit = content.Load<Texture2D>("exit");

            }

    }
```

Here are the Exception details :

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=La valeur ne peut pas être null. Nom du paramètre : Graphics
>   Device Cannot Be Null   Source=MonoGame.Framework   ParamName=Graphics
>   Device Cannot Be Null   StackTrace:
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D..ctor(GraphicsDevice
>   graphicsDevice, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean mipmap,
>   SurfaceFormat format, SurfaceType type, Boolean shared, Int32
>   arraySize)
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D..ctor(GraphicsDevice
>   graphicsDevice, Int32 width, Int32 height)
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.PlatformFromStream(GraphicsDevice
>   graphicsDevice, Stream stream)
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice
>   graphicsDevice, Stream stream)
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadRawAsset[T](String
>   assetName, String originalAssetName)
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T](String
>   assetName, Action`1 recordDisposableObject)
>          à Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName)
>          à Rogue_Like_LOL.Art.Load(ContentManager content) dans c:\Users\Monique Dumont\Programmation\Rogue Like LOL\Rogue Like
>   LOL\Art Manager\Art.cs:ligne 22
>          à Rogue_Like_LOL.Game1..ctor() dans c:\Users\Monique Dumont\Programmation\Rogue Like LOL\Rogue Like LOL\Game1.cs:ligne 34
>          à Rogue_Like_LOL.Program.Main() dans c:\Users\Monique Dumont\Programmation\Rogue Like LOL\Rogue Like LOL\Program.cs:ligne 17
>          à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: your textures are in "Content" right? not in any subfolder?

Comment: @DavorMlinaric Yes of course, I also checked if the .png were on "Copy always".

Comment: Content should be loaded either in `LoadContent` (more appropriate) or `Initialize` virtual methods of Game1 by overriding either of these. Note that when overriding Initialize, make sure to call `base.Initialize()` because that is what is actually initializing base game systems.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to load your content after the content manager is ready to be used. I am not sure if this would solve your problem, but it seems like a possible issue to me.

To do so:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    Art.Load(Content);
}
```